# How do I raise the redis vector index server limit?

Tags: vector, redis, vector-database, redis-stack-server, redis-search

I'm trying to index and search over 245k documents in redis and I get this error:
`redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Vector index initial capacity 245364 exceeded server limit (225861 with the given parameters)`

I'm running Redis in a docker container and tried to increase the resources, but it's still the same error. How can I raise the server limit?

Answer (score 1):

I added these environment params to docker, and it's working now:

```
REDISEARCH_ARGS= VSS_MAX_RESIZE 52428800000
```

Found it on the official docu here: https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/basic-constructs/configuration-parameters/